# Randomly Choose A Windows Form Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a program, and I have 81 textboxes. I need to be able to programmatically select a Windows Form Control in c#, and set it's text to be a certain string, and to change whether it is readonly and change background color. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Like this:

```
RandomTextbox.Text = MyStringValue;
RandomTextbox.ReadOnly = true;
RandomTextbox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
```

Comment: `I have 81 textboxs` you must hate the users

Comment: if they have systematic names then use reflection to find them

Comment: Use a DataGridView instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of the textboxes belong to the same parent control, you can do something like this:

```
var random = new Random();  // Put this somewhere to be called one time

var textboxes = parentControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
var randomTextbox = textboxes[random.Next(textboxes.Count)];

randomTextbox.Text = "I've been choooooooosen!";
```

Answer (score 2):

Name your TextBox's as TextBox1, TextBox2, ..., TextBox81

```
// generates a random value between 1 and 81
Random rnd = new Random();

// find the textbox and change its properties
TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("TextBox" + rnd.Next(1, 81).ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
    // change color, text, ect
```

Comment: ooh - i didnt know that existed

Comment: `.Find` returns `Control()` array https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find

Answer (score 0):

Find all the controls on your form which are `TextBox`:

```
var boxes = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where( x => x.GetType() == typeof( TextBox ) )
   .Cast<TextBox>().ToList();
```

Select a random one from the found list above and do something to it. Here the code sets the `Text` property to `Random Text`:

```
Random r = new Random();
int random = r.Next( boxes.Count() - 1);
boxes[ random ].Text = "Random Text";
```

Comment: Passing 0 to the constructor for Random should give you an identical set of results every time if I'm not mistaken... I think you want the parameterless constructor instead.